# setting Bing Maps Silverlight Control Property From Code Behind

Tags: c#, silverlight, bing-maps

I need to set the CredentialsProvider from code behind prior to load the control on page. I have "ApiKey" dependency property in code behind and binding it to Bing Maps silverlight Control but it doesn't work. It gives an error "invalid credentials" at run time.

Code Behind

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ApiKeyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ApiKey", typeof(string), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(""));
protected string ApiKey
{
    get { return this.GetValue(ApiKeyProperty) as string; }
    set { this.SetValue(ApiKeyProperty, value); }
}
```

XAML

```
<m:Map x:Name="map" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Margin="0" CredentialsProvider="{Binding ElementName=silverlightMap, Path=ApiKey}" 
               Mode="Road" MouseMove="map_MouseMove" MouseLeftButtonUp="map_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseLeftButtonDown="map_MouseLeftButtonDown"
               ViewChangeEnd="map_ViewChangeEnd"></m:Map>
```

The class name is MainPage and is being inherited from UserControl.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the ApiKey property get is returning your valid key?

Comment: my this problem is way too old. I had solved the problem by not using it. I will mark answer checking who gets highest votes in couple of days.

Answer (score 6):

```
CredentialsProvider = new ApplicationIdCredentialsProvider("AbcdEfghIjklMNnoP_4rlMTclX8iXiNYUYQnG3GPYoxABCDEmoj3cCBemAAG")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CredentialsProvider` property isn't of type string and doesn't automatically convert strings to a `CredentialsProvider` instance (how would it choose which sub-class to convert to?)

You'd be best off exposing a `CredentialsProvider` instance from your code. That way you can return either an API key or client token, perhaps based on your configuration file.

Comment: Yes I had tried this but CredentialsProvider is an abstract class and I can't create an instance of it.

Comment: There are two subclasses that you need to choose from depending on how you want to authenticate with Bing. That's the point - a string could convert to either of those two classes, so Bing doesn't automatically convert the string for you. Read the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.core.credentialsprovider.aspx

Answer (score 0):

After much travail, I finally discovered that this occurs when the Thread.CurrentUICulture is set to the invariant culture.
Be sure it is set to a specific culture (consider also setting Thread.CurrentCulture) in the App.Startup event handler, e.g.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

You do still need the credentials set properly using your AppID, of course. HTH.