# Invalid credentials with Bing Maps in Google Chrome

Tags: silverlight, google-chrome, bing-maps

We use the Bing Maps control in one of our Silverlight projects and it works well on all but one machine, where the `Invalid Credentials` message pops up after a few seconds. The issue occurs in Google Chrome only. In IE 11 or any other computer running Google Chrome, the message won't pop up. The control is created and configured programmatically:

```
var map = new Map();
map.CredentialsProvider = new ApplicationIdCredentialsProvider("...");
```

I checked the communication between Silverlight and the Bing servers using Fiddler and the responses received from Bing are identical on all machines. So the only difference is, that the Bing Maps control in Chrome decides to pop up the error message while the one in IE doesn't.

**What I've tried:**

- Tripple-checked the credentials (works everywhere else, so ...)
- Explicitly [set the culture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6192715/640901) of the application at runtime
- Switched from OS to the browser stack
- Cleared the Silverlight / browser cache
- Reinstalled Chrome and Silverlight on that machine
- Added and removed the system's proxy
- Used the application package (XAP) created by the build server (which works everywhere else, but not on that machine with Chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Adblock Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb) enabled, the `Invalid Credentials` message will pop up. Disabling Adblock for the website solved the problem.